# Subtract a constant from a column in Excel

Tags: excel

[image]=SUM(D5,-1)

Column D

```
134
23
232
```

I need to subtract 1 from each column

to get E

```
133
22
231
```

Comment: so why not just put `=D5 - 1` and copy/drag down?

Comment: Maybe it's the formatiing or whatever I get just -1 in all hte rows :(

Comment: So the cells are blank, are you sure your data isn't in column C with D hidden or something? Even formatting the numbers as text would not produce -1

Comment: @TimWilkinson, it would do using the `SUM` function

Comment: @CallumDA33 agreed but as the comment wasn't mentioned in his question I assumed he meant when trying `=D5-1`

Comment: Check the image guys

Comment: @Max, it would seem like your numbers are strings as they are left aligned in your picture. Does either `D5-1` or `SUM(D5*1,-1)` work?

Comment: Then my guess is you have something in the cells that you cannot see that is keeping excel from recognizing the value as a number.  Try this `=Trim(Clean(A5))-1` and copy/drag down.  If that does not work you will need to look into your data and find what it is that is keeping Excel from recognizing the data as numbers.

Comment: Did that, copied all od column D into colum H, trimmed and cleaned and the nformatted column H to a number with precision 0 .. but it still doesn't work!! :(

Comment: BUMP! PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  D      E
134    =D1-1
23     =D2-1
232    =D3-1
```